# Is there a way to programmatically change a font size?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to programmatically change a font size?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Narrow"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Narrow"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In this case, I'd like to give the customer the ability to change the font size from 14 to another font size.

Comment: You mean at runtime or by configuration?

Comment: uiLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
uiLabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;uiLabel.FontSize = 16;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the customer is changing the font size of a label via a textbox input.

```
//XAML

<Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="box1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="90,192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="This is a label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Enter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btn1_Click"/>
    </Grid>

//Programmatically changing font
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.FontSize = int.Parse(box1.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

**i 'do in this way .**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="baseStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}"></Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}"></Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}"></Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}"></Style>
        <!-- ComboBox, RadioButton, CheckBox, etc... -->
    </Window.Resources>
```

That way, if I want to change ALL the controls, I'd just have to change the "baseStyle" style, the rest would just inherit from it. (That's what BasedOn property those, you can also extend the base style if you create other setters inside of the inherited style) You can use different different style.

**You can do it programmatically like this**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uiLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        uiLabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        uiLabel.FontSize = 16;
    }
```